# Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String. Converting string to map

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Below is my code. I get this error "com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String" . Please help.

```
 du = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("storename");
    du.keepSynced(true);
    du.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            GenericTypeIndicator<Map<String, String>> genericTypeIndicator = new GenericTypeIndicator<Map<String, String>>() {
            };
            Map<String, String> map = dataSnapshot.getValue(genericTypeIndicator);
            name.setText(map.get("ownerName"));
            storename.setText(map.get("compName"));
            storeaddr.setText(map.get("address"));
            ph1.setText("Ph: " + map.get("phoneNumber"));
            gst.setText(map.get("gstNum"));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        }
    });
```

[image: Firebase Image]

Comment: you should be subscribing to a store instead you r subscribing to the parent node containing all the stores

Comment: you should loop through you are getting a list of HashMap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're loading all data from `/storename` . Since there may be multiple stores under there, you'll need to loop over `dataSnapshot.getChildren()` to get to each individual store.

So:

```
du = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("storename");
du.keepSynced(true);
du.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
            GenericTypeIndicator<Map<String, String>> genericTypeIndicator = new GenericTypeIndicator<Map<String, String>>() {
            };
            Map<String, String> map = dataSnapshot.getValue(genericTypeIndicator);
            name.setText(map.get("ownerName"));
            storename.setText(map.get("compName"));
            storeaddr.setText(map.get("address"));
            ph1.setText("Ph: " + map.get("phoneNumber"));
            gst.setText(map.get("gstNum"));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        throw error.toException(); // never ignore errors
    }
});
```